# Recurring "Allow USB debugging?" popup during a test run

Tags: adb

Per my work-around here [./gradlew test connectedAndroidTest erases my getFilesDir() folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57433975/gradlew-test-connectedandroidtest-erases-my-getfilesdir-folder/60174578#60174578), I test on two ONN tablets using a Ruby `Rakefile` that looks a little bit like this:

```
task default: [ :unit_test_and_install, :espresso_test ]

task :unit_test_and_install do
    sh './gradlew --console=verbose test installDebug installDebugAndroidTest'
end

task :espresso_test do
    devices = `adb devices`
    serial_numbers = devices.split("\n")[1..-1].map{|q| q.split("\t")[0] }

    threads = serial_numbers.map do |sn|
        Thread.new do
            sh "adb -s #{sn} shell am instrument -w -r -e package com.mycorp.myapp -e disableAnalytics true " +
                    "com.mycorp.myapp.test/androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner | tee tests_#{sn}.txt"
        end
    end

    threads.each &:join

    serial_numbers.each do |sn|
        grop = `grep "^OK .*tests" tests_#{sn}.txt`

        if grop == ''
            sh "cat tests_#{sn}.txt"
            abort 'FAILURES on ' + sn
        end
    end

end
```

The problem is the `adb -s WHATEVER shell am instrument` line. Even though it launches the JUnit tests correctly, sometimes the tablet puts up its "Allow USB debugging?" requester. (The one that says "The computer's RSA key fingerprint is...")

The tests run whether I tap the requester or not, and it usually does not pop up. Test runs and debugging runs from Android Studio or `./gradlew` don't trigger the popup. But how do I get rid of it?

Comment: does the fingerprint change each time the dialog is shown? Please note that development questions are off-topic here.

Comment: this is just initial pop up for each new host, should not happen. adb does generate new keys in `.android` under certain circumstances in home folder, maybe you did run your tests from different users? in any case you should grep connection state and wait for authorize in your script. if you want to skip this you need to modify devices `ro.adb.secure`

Comment: please stop editing this question. This is not wikipedia, Third parties should only edit a question to fix a typographical error or something